# Let A ⊂ B ⊂ C. If C/A and C/B are normal extensions then B/A is also normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let A ⊂ B ⊂ C. If C/A and C/B are normal extensions then B/A is also normal. Is that true? If it is not I couldn’t find a contra-example for that? Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Try for example the splitting field of $X^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. That should provide a counter example.